Does the snapshot isolation level transaction wait for other transactions to complete before it can start working on its own?
If we have ongoing unfinished transactions with any isolation level, does a new transaction with snapshot isolation level wait for their completion before it starts taking a snapshot?
Sorry for My English.

No, it doesn't. As per Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server doc:

The net effect of snapshot isolation is that the transaction sees all of the data as it existed at the start of the transaction, without honoring or placing any locks on the underlying tables.

also from the same doc:

Snapshot isolation uses an optimistic concurrency model. If a snapshot transaction attempts to commit modifications to data that has changed since the transaction began, the transaction will roll back and an error will be raised.


If I run multiple transactions with the snapshot isolation level, these transaction levels use a common tmpdb schema to store copies. Won't using these shared resources lead to locks?

I've updated answer, snapshot isolation uses optimistic concurrency (to remember the version of the rows affected - do transaction - on committing the transaction check if rows have changed their versions in the table or not - fail or commit accordingly); which is an alternative to locks - a pessimistic concurrency way (to lock the rows - do transaction - on committing release the locks)
